Matches the same two digits that were captured in the first group
select *
from bha b 
where b.bks similar to '\d{2}[A-Z](\d{2})\d\\1';

The purpose is to regex but bks is in the form








12A56856


12A12812


12A898389



Although I already have this data in my database, the query is still not successful.
I hope you can help



Input:




45A78963


78C79364


14A56356


56K78978






Output:




14A56356


56K78978




There is an extra backslash before \1. Use b.bks ~ '^\d{2}[A-Z](\d{2})\d\1$' and it works as expected.

This - select * from bha b where b.bks ~ '^\d{2}[A-Z](\d{2})\d\1$'; - should work. Does it?

Oh my god. i try it and it works as expected.Thanks so much

@NguyễnTuấnHưng I don't think this pattern covers your third example, where the two identical pairs of digits are separated by more than one digit: 12A 89 83 89. Was that a typo, or do you need to catch those as well?

I don't think this was a typo. I think you tried to avoid the error:

ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid backreference number


Which was caused by your attempt to use a backreference \1 in a SIMILAR TO regex syntax. The message is a bit confusing because Postgres' implementation of SIMILAR TO simply doesn't support backreferences, at all - which I think it should say openly instead of sounding like you're doing them wrong.
Your addition of another backslash to get a \\1 got rid of the error, but that's because this made the pattern look for a literal backslash \ followed by a literal 1 in that spot, matching things like '56K789\1'.
@Stefanov's fix works because the ~ operator uses POSIX regular expression syntax, which does support backreferences.
If you need to handle your third example 12A 89 83 89 with two identical pairs of digits separated by more than one digit, add a + (or a * if you also allow zero digits between those pairs):
demo at db<>fiddle
select *
from bha b 
where b.bks ~ '^\d{2}[A-Z](\d{2})\d+\1$';


The idea proposed by @d r can get you some performance, then some more performance thanks to index use, at the expense of more verbose code, if you replace the regex entirely with much simpler expressions involving basic substrings:
select *
from bha b 
where substring(b.bks,4,2)=right(b.bks,2)
  and array[ left(b.bks,1)
            ,substring(b.bks,2,1)
            ,substring(b.bks,4,1)
            ,substring(b.bks,5,1)
            ,left(right(b.bks,2),1)
            ,right(b.bks,1) ] <@ '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}'
  and substring(b.bks,3,1) = any('{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,
                                   N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}');


That was my typo. Thank you for that answer. Now I'm getting the same error on elasticSearch. If you have experience with it, please help me

{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "bks.keyword": {
        "value": """[0-9]{2}[A-Z]([0-9]{2})[0-9]/1""" ,
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}


@NguyễnTuấnHưng Same problem: ElasticSearch uses Apache Lucene that doesn't seem to support backreferences. Related thread.

If your data realy is structured as in the data provided then there is no need for regex - it could be done simply using SubStr() function. Just compare your string's positions 4,5 against positions 7,8. You can add another test checking if the positions are numbers or not:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
   tbl as 
      ( Select 1 as id, '45A78963' as test_str Union All
        Select 2, '78C79364' Union All
        Select 3, '14A56356' Union All
        Select 4, '56K78978' 
      )

--    S Q L :
Select    *
From      tbl
Where     SubStr(test_str, 4, 2) = SubStr(test_str, 7, 2)

/*    R e s u l t : 
        ID TEST_STR
---------- --------
         3 14A56356
         4 56K78978    */

